# In IOS, while in "Edit Mode", how do I add a new section with cell to a static UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

It appears I have hit a dead end trying to figure this out.

I'm working on an app that contains a static UITableView with 3 sections, each section containing one cell. Each cell contains a UITextField. On the navigation bar, I have an edit button, once clicked the UITextFields are enabled--allowing the user to modify the text.

I was wondering if someone could guide me on the right direction. I want to add an extra section with one cell, containing a "Delete" button.

The best example I could find for what I am trying to do is in the Contacts app. Notice here, there's no delete button.[image: Regular view, no delete button]

Once edit mode is enabled, an extra section with cell is added, which holds a delete button. [image: edit mode, delete button appears]

I have already setup the code to enable edit mode by overriding the setEditing method.

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if editing {
        // enable textfields
    }
    else {
       // disable textfields 
       // save data
    }
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: When you stop using static cells, set `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` to return 3 instead of 2 and call `reloadData` on the UITableView, then what are you doing?

Comment: I never implemented that method. I read somewhere that it isn't necessary to implement the data source methods for a tableview if it's static. I'm still kind of new to IOS Development. Should I be implementing it?

Answer (score 2):

When you enable or disable editing, reload your table view:

```
self.tableView!.reloadData()
```

From there, you can return some different values depending on whether you're editing or not.  Here's some examples:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    var sectionCount = 1
    if tableView.editing {

        sectionCount += 1

    }
    return sectionCount

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let lastSection = 1
    if section == lastSection {

        return 1

    }
    return 5

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let lastSection = 1
    if (indexPath.section == lastSection) {

        // return the special delete cell

    } else {

        // return other cells

    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let lastSection = 1
    if (indexPath.section == lastSection) {

        // handle delete cell

    } else {

        // handle other cells

    }

}
```